# Intellij JBoss - Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, jvm

I am using IntelliJ 2020.1 Ultimate and have a JBoss 7.0.2 server that I want to run from IntelliJ.

I have added it as a configuration:

[image]

But when I try start the server, I get the following error:

> IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar"
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 64088
>   4a7ed3b5-cfb6-4196-b997-396c16d8c06f
>   /Users/richardmarais/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/compile-server
>   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx2048m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms2048m OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0 Error occurred
>   during initialization of VM Initial heap size set to a larger value
>   than the maximum heap size

My `idea.vmoptions` are the default values:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
```

**Question**

Do you know how I can fix the above error to get JBoss to start?

Comment: It looks like the minum heap is equal to the maximum. Try to low down the minimum (Xms) or viceversa

Comment: @sigur, thanks for the comment. Where do I set this? in the `idea.vmoptions` (but why would defaults be wrong)? or in the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`? or in the IntelliJ Jboss configurations `VM Options`?

Comment: If I: `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms1024m"`, the log still says: `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms2048m`. So I am not sure where this is set?

Comment: I can update the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` with `open -a TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile` to `-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms2048m`, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set any global environment variables to patch the VM options.

Unset `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and specify the proper VM Options in the Run/Debug configuration for the server:

`-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

It should be more than enough for any project. I doubt that you really need 5GB initial heap size.

Also note that IntelliJ IDEA `.vmoptions` doesn't affect the options for the apps that you start from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing this.

```
open -a TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile
```

then:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx4096m -Xms128m"
```